# ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2 bug?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

So far I've been using ASP.NET MVC 3 BETA. Everything was working fine till the update to RC2 version. Of course I've read [ScottGu's article about RC2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx).

My problem is following. Basically I have 2 controllers:

```
   public class DynamicPageController : Controller
   {          
      public ActionResult Redirect(string resource, int? pageNumber, int? id)
      {       
      }
   }

   public class SystemController : Controller
   {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
      }
   }
```

In the Globals.asax I have routes like this:

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
         routes.MapRoute(
            "SystemRoute",
            "System/{action}",
            new { controller = "System", action = "Index" }
            );

         routes.MapRoute(
            "PageRoute",
            "{resource}/{id}/{pageNumber}",
            new { controller = "DynamicPage", action = "Redirect", resource = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = UrlParameter.Optional, id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
   }
```

In the code, I have simple link creation:

```
System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper u = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(context);
string url = u.Action("Index", "System");
```

**and the url is "/my_app/System" in both versions (BETA and RC2)**

But the code below (the syntax is the same as above, only controller and action names are different):

```
string url = u.Action("Redirect", "DynamicPage", new RouteValueDictionary(new { resource = "Home" }));
```

**gives url which is null in RC2. It should be (and in fact in BETA was) "/my_app/Home"**

Why ? Is it a bug ? How can I create url for my "**DynamicPage**" controller ?

Regards

*BTW:* From where can I now download ASP.NET MVC BETA version along with ASP.NET Web Pages 1.0 installers ? Since RC2 announcement I have problems finding mentioned 2 installers. Normally I would upgrade my code but this issue described above makes me stay with BETA for a while, since I have no time for migration and testing everything now.

**UPDATE**

The solution I've used for the case, when I have two optional parameters existing one after another, is to add new *PageRouteCore* route just before existed *PageRoute* route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "PageRouteCore",
            "{resource}",
            new {controller = "DynamicPage", action = "Redirect"}
            );
```

This is basically the same route but without optional parameters. The url creation behaves now as I expected it to behave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yeah it's a bug](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/14/update-on-asp-net-mvc-3-rc2-and-a-workaround-for-a-bug-in-it.aspx).

Also you could [download ASP.NET MVC RC1 from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a920ccee-1397-4feb-824a-2dfefee47d54).

Comment: Hey, thanks for replay but unfortunately that hotfix did NOT resolve my issue. Mabye this what I have is another bug ?

Comment: @Jarek, now that I look more carefully at your routes and the way you are generating your url, you never specify the `id` parameter (you have only specified the `resource` parameter). In your routes you have specified that the `{id}` part is optional but this is not possible because only the last part of a route can be optional (in your case this would be `pageNumber`). IIRC in RC2 they have enforced this rule so I would say that this makes perfect sense. This is not a bug. Your routes should be fixed.

Comment: can you explain me why they done that ? Why I can't have 2 or more optional parameters ?

Comment: I understand that, but I'm wondering why it cannot be assumed, that if there are 2 optional parameters, and there is only one provided in the url, the provided parameter is the first one from the definition of the route ? Suppose the route looks foo/{a}/{b}. When the url is foo/1 or foo/2 it could be assumed that in the first case a=1 and in the second a=2. The same rule could be right for more parameters - the succeeded optional parameters are choosen to be assigned to the values from url. It makes sense isn't it ?